# Activate JButton with Keyboard

Tags: java, swing, keyboard, key, jbutton

This is my JButton, "I can show full code",

```
        JButton cor =new JButton();
        cor.setText("Coor");
        mainframe.add(cor);
        window.getContentPane().add(mainframe);
        window.pack();
        window.setVisible(true);
```

I need help, with, HOW to activate this button using keyboard, for example press "CTRL + A"

I  have red some websites and find out that i have to use "Key Bindings", but still can get how to do it.

Please don't say that this topic is duplicated, because previous topics doesn't help me.

```
cor.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("F2"),"act"); 

Action act = new AbstractAction() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                PointerInfo a = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo();
                Point b = a.getLocation();
                int xC = (int) b.getX();
                int yC = (int) b.getY();
                textArea.replaceSelection("X-Coordinates:" + xC + "  Y-Coordinates: " + yC + "\n");
            }
        };
```

Comment: No one wants to see full code but consider showing your code where you attempt to use Key Bindings. This is the best way for us to know what you might be doing wrong. Best to post an [sscce](http://sscce.org). re `Please don't say that this topic is duplicated, because previous topics doesn't help me.` Consider avoiding making stipulations on the answers we can give. We're all volunteers after all; you're not paying us. Instead tell us exactly what about key bindings confuses you, and show this with your code.

Comment: I used this code: cor.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("F2"), "none");

Comment: Show in your question above, not in comments. Also show how you use the ActionMap. The solution is of course to use Key Bindings correctly. No one will want to re-write the tutorial for you, so to get specific help, you'll want to show more code (as an edit to your question).

Comment: Have edit the main question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to change a property to JButton, to get a short path (in this example, ALT+C)

```
cor.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_C);
```

Your code will look like this:

```
    JButton cor =new JButton();
    cor.setText("Coor");
    cor.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_C);
    mainframe.add(cor);
    window.getContentPane().add(mainframe);
    window.pack();
    window.setVisible(true);
```

You also get an extra, letter "C" in the Button name is underscored showing to user the aid.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if that is the reason of your problem but from your example I see that in `getInputMap` you are linking key with name of the action, but you forgot to use `getActionMap` to link name of action with actual action object like

```
cor.getActionMap().put("act", act);
```

Also to crate <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> you can use

```
cor.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(
                KeyStroke.getKeyStroke('A',InputEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK), "act");
```